# Delphi XE4 consuming CPU even when idle

Tags: windows, delphi, delphi-xe4

I'm using Delphi XE4 on an Athlon II 3.4 GHz, 8 GB memmory, with Windows 10. bds.exe is consuming up to 15% of CPU, even when the IDE is idle. Is XE4 not compatible with Windows 10?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is XE4 not compatible with Windows 10?

XE4 is compatible with Windows 10.

Comment: Any ideia why the IDE, even idle, is comsuming CPU?

Comment: No idea. I just answered the question you asked.